# passing a widget that has setState to another page without stateful/stateless widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, setstate

Is Any Way  How to pass a widget function to another page that is without any stateless/stateful? The file only includes widgets such as textfields, buttons and etc. I am trying not to cluster every fields in one page. Any helps/ideas would be appreciated!

Main.dart

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<Main Page> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
// bool for toggling password
  bool isSecuredPasswordField = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
// widget function that I need to pass on widget_fields.dart
 Widget togglePassword() {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          isSecuredPasswordField = !isSecuredPasswordField;
        });
      },
      icon: isSecuredPasswordField
          ? const Icon(Icons.visibility)
          : const Icon(Icons.visibility_off),
    );
  }
}
```

widget_fields.dart

```
Widget userPasswordField(_passwordUserCtrlr) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
    child: TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      controller: _passwordUserCtrlr,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        isDense: true,
        suffixIcon: togglePassword(), //<-- I wanna call that function here
        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCECECE)),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCECECE)),
        ),
        hintText: 'Password',
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
          fontSize: 14,
        ),
        fillColor: const Color(0xFFFEFEFE),
        filled: true,
      ),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          return "Please enter your password.";
        } else if (value.length < 8) {
          return "Password should be min. 8 characters.";
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: You can pass it like any variable. What have you tried?

Comment: @flutternewbiee Kindly Check My Answer surly it's help full for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass functions like any other variable. I made a full working example that's different than yours to show a more minimal example but you can apply the same logic for your code

*main.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'column.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Widget returnSomeText() {
    return const Text("test");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: createColumn(returnSomeText));
  }
}
```

*column.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget createColumn(Function widgetFunction) {
  return Column(
    children: [widgetFunction(), widgetFunction()],
  );
}
```

As you can see the `togglePassword` from your code corresponds to `returnSomeText` in mine. and `userPasswordField` is like `createColumn`. But it must be said that it's not recommended to use helper functions like `createColumn` here but to turn it into a `StatelessWidget`, like this for example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CreateColumn extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function widgetFunction;
  const CreateColumn({Key? key, required this.widgetFunction}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [widgetFunction(), widgetFunction()],
    );
  }
}
```

And then in main.dart:

```
return Scaffold(body: CreateColumn(widgetFunction: returnSomeText));
```

See also this YouTube video: [Widgets vs helper methods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOyq-eTRhvo)

Comment: thank you so much, the logic is perfect and now it works on me! will try to refractor my code into what you've suggested. I didn't know the whole tree would rebuild when using setState I thought it would only setState the function wherein I put my setState.
Are there any more suggestions on how do I improve my current code aside from the widgets vs helper methods? Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

**This is Example that how you call Widget in another class:**

```
  class MainApge extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApge({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainApge> createState() => _MainApgeState();
}

class _MainApgeState extends State<MainApge> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ContainerTextFields.customsTextField(
          "User Name",
          'enter name',
          userNameController,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**This is Custom Widget Class:**

```
 class ContainerTextFields {
      static Widget customsTextField(
          String label, String cusHintText, TextEditingController _controller) {
        return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: SizeConfig.screenHeight! * 0.05,
                  top: SizeConfig.screenHeight! * 0.03),
              child: Text(
                label,
                style: AppStyle.kUnSyncedDialogeText.copyWith(
                    color: AppColors.kTextFieldLabelColorGrey,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: SizeConfig.screenHeight! * 0.02,
                left: SizeConfig.screenHeight! * 0.042,
                right: SizeConfig.screenWidth! * 0.042),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                height: SizeConfig.screenHeight! * 0.065,
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: _controller,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: cusHintText,
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: AppColors.kLoginPopUpColor,
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ]);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create class like GlobalWidget for example, like this:

```
class GlobalWidget {

 // widget function that I need to pass on widget_fields.dart
 Widget togglePassword(Function()? onPressed, bool value) {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      icon: value
          ? const Icon(Icons.visibility)
          : const Icon(Icons.visibility_off),
    );
  }

}
```

And You can call the Widget like that :

```
GlobalWidget().togglePassword(() => setState(() {
    isSecuredPasswordField = !isSecuredPasswordField;
  }), isSecuredPasswordField)
```

Comment: setState doesn't work if this class Global Widget is not inside a Widget Tree of a Stateful Widget. Please correct me if I'm wrong I just did it by now. Thank you!

Comment: Yes it's true, but you can pass it as a parameter !!! Let me update my solution !!!

Comment: This could be improved by calling the class `TogglePassword`, putting the `onPressed` and `value` into final members and renaming the method to `build(BuildContext context)`. i.e. create a proper widget instead of a function returning one, which is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the widget as parameter to child widget:

```
class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyTextField({Key? key,
    this.togglePassword,
    this.passwordUserCtrlr
  })
      : super(key: key);

  final Widget? togglePassword;
  final TextEditingController? passwordUserCtrlr;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        obscureText: true,
        controller: passwordUserCtrlr,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          isDense: true,
          suffixIcon: togglePassword, //<-- I wanna call that function here
          prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCECECE)),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCECECE)),
          ),
          hintText: 'Password',
          hintStyle: const TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            fontSize: 14,
          ),
          fillColor: const Color(0xFFFEFEFE),
          filled: true,
        ),
        validator: (value) {
          if (value!.isEmpty) {
            return "Please enter your password.";
          } else if (value.length < 8) {
            return "Password should be min. 8 characters.";
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And can easily call from main widget:

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
// bool for toggling password
  bool isSecuredPasswordField = true;
  TextEditingController? passwordUserCtrlr = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyTextField(
      togglePassword: togglePassword(),
      passwordUserCtrlr: passwordUserCtrlr,
    );
  }
// widget function that I need to pass on widget_fields.dart
  Widget togglePassword() {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          isSecuredPasswordField = !isSecuredPasswordField;
        });
      },
      icon: isSecuredPasswordField
          ? const Icon(Icons.visibility)
          : const Icon(Icons.visibility_off),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What you are trying to do is impossible in the Flutter framework. You cannot call methods belonging to other widgets

Also, it is discouraged to use function to return widgets as this impacts the framework's ability to optimize the build process.

One possible solution is to package your complete password entry in a set of custom (statefull) widgets. You can collect those into a single source file if you like. Be sure to create a class for every widget.